# How to investigate display problems?

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, kde

I'm running Kubuntu 15.04 and from time to time my display turns completely black. The only thing then that's visible to me is the mouse pointer and after pressing ALT+F2 the "command run dialog".

Since I'm new to Kubuntu I'm not sure where to start looking for hints on the problem that would narrow down possible problem sources. Which log files etc. do I have to look for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today I encountered the same problem.

Let's do this:

1. Press `Ctrl + Alt + F1`
2. Log in as root
3. Type `startx` and hit `Enter`

It should tell you if the X has encountered any problem and where the log file is.

If the X is already running, let's restart it using `sudo service sddm restart`

Comment: thank you very much burian. "unfortunately" I can't test this immediately, so I have to wait for the next random crash. do you know if this has been reported already?

Comment: No, I don't know. I am new tu Kubuntu (from yesterday), there are too many issues as far as I can see.